# Opening first lines of large files in VIM

Tags: vim, gvim

I run Windows XP and gvim7.2.
I want to inspect a large (130 MB) XML file with VIM. Is it possible to simply open the first 1000 lines of the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the main problem of vim is not the file size, but the syntax highlighting of the file. i use the '[large file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506)' script to disable such timeconsuming things when working on large files.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can just:

```
head -1000 large_file.xml | vim -
```

Comment: head/tail for windows: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You may use `head` or `tail` to cut specific parts of the file and then open them in vim. In your specific example, you could do:

```
head -1000 large_file.xml > small_file.xml
```

Then you would be able to open small_file.xml in gvim.

This, of course, you have the head and tail utilities installed.