# gVim crashing while opening 8GB text file

Tags: gvim

I have an 8GB text file which contains output from a structural analysis program. The output is in the form of lines corresponding to time steps - with each line representing state of a system at a time step.

Notepad++ refuses to open the file as expected.
While gVim crashes after a minute full of attempts to open the file.

From what I have read, gVim is capable of handling such large files. So is there some adjustment that needs to be done in gVim settings?
Or is there some better software?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/121313/opening-first-lines-of-large-files-in-vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim has many options and features (syntax highliting, swap file, etc), some which should be disabled to better (faster) open a large file : [try those](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Faster_loading_of_large_files)

Comment: in addition, you should probably change your statusbar (if it shows lines, etc). And disable modeline? etc. Another good list : http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-5.12

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WMWMZ.png This is what I get now. Atleast its not crashing.

Comment: it's trying to load it all in memory. You can add swap size ... or try another editor that will only load the part you look at. Or you should use "less" if you just need to watch the content of the file and not edit it (or use head & tail, and grep, to trim out whatever you don't need).

Comment: or even try the ones suggested in this so page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files (glogg looks nice)

Comment: ok, so it was loading it all in the ram, so for the time being I fetched a computer with 16GB RAM and gVim is up and running. problem solved for now - altough I am trying glogg and other options in the meantime. Thanks!